# How to add database parameter to wikipedia chembox?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I'm trying to create a bot to add a biological's database to each compound in wikipedia but am first testing out in single compounds (glucose for example). My idea is to add the ID to the box on the right of each compound's webpage. 
However, it appears I cannot do so because the biological database I'm trying to add is not in the wikipedia's chembox identifiers list:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Chembox_Identifiers

How can I add the database?

Comment: Probably the easiest is to just ask for help on the talk page. That way you can also be sure you did not accidentally circumvent some kind of community consensus process.

Comment: Yes - start a thread at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_talk:Chembox explaining what links you wish to add and why and someone will help out. Add {{ping|Smartse}} if you like and I will take a look too.